# How does the Bone Orchard work in Bang! Wild West Show

Tags: bang

In Bang! When the Bone Orchard is still active, can the player return to the game many times or just once?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can return to the game multiple times while BONE ORCHARD is in play.

[image: Bone Orchard card]

Like a lot of rules in Bang! this is covered in the original Italian rules but was left out of the English translation.

Luckily the publisher has this covered in their [English FAQ](https://www.dvgiochi.com/giochi/wildwestshow/download/bang_wild_west_show_faq_eng.pdf) under *Q21*.

> Q21. If I come back in play with Bone Orchad and I am killed again,
> if the Bone Orchard is still in play when it is my next turn, do I
> come back in play again?
> A. Yes, you may come back into play at the beginning of each of your
> turn while the Bone Orchard is play